# Sensor streaming data generator with Apache Kafka

Tags: database, apache-kafka, stream, time-series, benchmarking

For benchmarking purposes, I have to simulate an online data stream (Time Series data), to be ingested by various databases.

In this particular use case, Time Series data should be recorded at very high frequencies.

I would process this stream with Apache Kafka.

Stream is essentially composed by many **real valued numbers**, with their **timestamp** and a **text label**.

I have seen many Kafka producer examples, but noone fitted my use case really good: how can I use Kafka in order to GENERATE and PROCESS such a data stream??

**EDIT:**

Using python APIs, I am currently able to directly send data to various databases. The remaining issue regards now speed: my target frequency is near to 15kHz.

I can barely reach 2kHz using the same (multi-threaded) Python script.

Any suggestion?